# calculating a chromatic polynomial

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am going through some questions in the  **"Bondy,Murty - Graph Theory with applications"**  book, and I have stumbled upon the following question:

*calculate the Chromatic Polynomial of the following graph :* 

 [image]

I figured I need to use the recursive method, meaning to rid one of the edges, but I can't figure out which way I should go about it.

 The only way I see to solve this is repeating that method several times(which I did and took a while...) ,
 but is there an easier way to solve it that I am missing?

Comment: Sometimes you do have to use the recursive method several times, but I think you can get away with just using it once here, if you're clever (and if I haven't missed something). If you join the top and bottom vertices by an edge, I think you get a graph that's easy to do, and if you identify the top and bottom vertices, I think you get a graph that's easy to do. Try it!

Answer (score 3):

Hmm. The chromatic polynomial, if I remember right, is a formula for the number of ways to color the graph (properly) given a supply of $x$ colors? Your graph has only $6$ vertices; that should be small enough to figure out by hand without knowing anything. Let's see. The top and bottom vertices either get the same color or different colors; let's count the two cases separately, and add.

**Top and bottom vertices same color:** $x$ ways to color the top and bottom; then $(x-1)(x-2)$ ways to color the two vertices on the left; likewise $(x-1)(x-2)$ ways for the two vertices on the right; so $x(x-1)^2(x-2)^2$ ways.

**Top and bottom vertices different colors:** $x(x-1)$ ways to color the top and bottom vertices; then $(x-2)(x-3)$ ways to color the vertices on the left, same on the right, so $x(x-1)(x-2)^2(x-3)^2$ ways.

**Add:**
$$x(x-1)^2(x-2)^2+x(x-1)(x-2)^2(x-3)^2=x(x-1)(x-2)^2[(x-1)+(x-3)^2=x(x-1)(x-2)^2(x^2-5x+8).$$
Is that the right answer?

Comment: There's no final solution in the book, but I got the same result when using the recursive method. Thank you!